# Series identity of Laguerre polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, orthogonal-polynomials

This came up in the computation of an ensemble average in quantum mechanics. According to Mathematica, we have the curious identity
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-bn)L_n(2a) = \frac{\exp\left(b+\frac{2a}{1-e^b}\right)}{e^b-1}
\end{equation}
for real $a,b$ and $b \neq 0$. How would one prove this? I have been unable to find a reference for this identity. I would conjecture that this is somehow related to the generating function just by its form, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating polynomial of Laguerre functions is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n L_n(x) = \dfrac{\exp\left(-\dfrac{tx}{1-t}\right)}{1-t}$$

Comment: Ah, so take $t\to e^{-b}$ and we are done. Thanks.